# bundles sizes are 2-3 times larger after ng serve vs ng build

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

When I do ng build and then ng serve I get bundle sizes 2-3 times larger than with ng build only.

When I do ng build its put to /dist folder.

When I do ng server the /dist folder is deleted and I can not find that folder anywhere.

Maybe these problems depend from each other don`t know.

So why that difference?

```
> ng build
Date: 2018-01-10T21:35:10.257Z
Hash: dce2b372c0c3a2ce2361
Time: 24205ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 322 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 445 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 211 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 4.59 MB [initial] [rendered]

> ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-01-10T21:39:13.885Z
Hash: 7a1869ea0e109abfb536
Time: 22658ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 778 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 1.3 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 594 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 12.8 MB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty normal. Basically it's because with `ng serve` there's no proper bundling and tree-shaking. `ng build` in turn uses some basic tree-shaking. You can get more details here: [The Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Compiler](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) and here: [Angular CLI Wiki - build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

Comment: Is that really true? Your link says otherwise - "JIT compilation is the default when you run the build-only or the build-and-serve-locally CLI commands:"

Comment: You're right. I've made a mistake because I use `--prod ` flag (which uses AOT) by default. I've edited my answer and added link to Angular CLI Wiki.